# Can running the same model on CPU and Edge TPU yield different results?

Tags: google-coral, tflite, edge-tpu, tflm

I'm currently using Dev Micro board and have been experimenting with the YamNeT model from the examples provided. When running the same model on a CPU compared the an edge tpu, i'm observing different results. is it possible for the hardware difference to influence the outcomes in such a manner?

YamNet Example! CPU(CM7)
Results:
153: 0.500000
147: 0.421875

YamNet Example! TPU
Results:
153: 0.500000
147: 0.351562

I tried running some models on both cpu and tpu, and found different inference output.
I expect the result to be same regardless of hardware since it is same model.